# Resolving injection of multiple strings with Dagger Hilt

Tags: kotlin, androidx, dagger-hilt

I have created a @Module in my project which has 2 functions returning Strings.
Since they both are of same type, I have added @Qualifiers as well

```
@Provides
@ApiURL
fun getBaseURL():String{
return BuildConfig.BASE_URL
}

@Provides
@UserName
fun getName():String{
return name;
}
```

`Name` is directly used in TextView while `ApiURL` has a dependency tree as it is required for Retrofit and then `APIService` and `APIHelper` class.

In my Activity I need instances for both them.

`Name` I'm able to directly inject while for `APIHelper` - even if I add Qualifier to the complete chain of dependency graph, it still gives error for not being able to Provide the dependency.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Could you show the exact error message? Also would be nice to upload some examples of your modules, inject members.

Comment: Did you add inject your strings using '@Inject @Qualifier lateinit var string: String' ?

Comment: @Andrew I was trying to inject a string in the constructor of my ViewModel and was getting error after moving it out of the constructor and making it a lateinit var the code compiles but not sure why